# LLVM & Clang++

Tags: c, llvm, c++

В [туториале](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html) по применению clang в LLVM пример разобран на чистом С. Вопрос: требуется С++ перевести в байткод. Я так понимаю нужно использовать clang++ вместо clang? И с какими аргументами? Потому что при попытке использовать с аргументами, как в примере для clang, валится линковщик (fatal error - unresolved externals). Прошу прощения за некую сумбурность в постановке вопроса.

Comment: Обновите ссылку.

Comment: криво вставилась ссылка на туториал -
http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html

Comment: попробую расписать поподробнее:
1. компилирую .cpp в .bc файл (байткод) - проходит
2. утилитой llc создаю .obj
3. мелкомягким линковщиком link.exe пытаюсь собрать (строка: > link hello.obj -defaultlib:libcmt -out:hello.exe) - тут все валится.

Comment: В общем, если кто в курсе, как под виндой из C++ файла с помощью clang++ получить .bc файл (байткод LLVM), который потом соберется линковщиком в .exe - буду рад услышать.

Comment: Убедитесь, что и компиляция, и линковка выполняются для одинаковой конфигурации (x86/x64 и Debug/Release). Также уточните, пожалуйста, что значит "все валится"? Есть ли какие-нибудь сообщения об ошибках?

Comment: ТС уже года два тут не появлялся, вряд ли он что-то уточнит. :)

Comment: Вопрос был отвечен 7 лет назад на англоязычном SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643398/how-to-compile-a-c-program-in-llvm-using-clang